# How to find text match from "class" HTML label?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to parse HTML and find text match "product-size _product-size " (without any other words like "disabled _disabled ").
So I used BeautifulSoup and cut pice of HTML code I needed

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL =.......

headers = {"User-Agent": .......}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find("div", class_="size-list")
print("Find size-list \n" + str(div) +'\n')
```

Got this

```
<div class="size-list" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="size-10" 
    class="product-size _product-size disabled _disabled " 
    data-sku="01122345" data-name="10">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" id="size-10" 
            disabled="disabled" class="_sizeInput" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="10">10</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-11" 
    class="product-size _product-size disabled _disabled " 
    data-sku="01122346" data-name="11">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="11" name="size" id="size-11" 
            disabled="disabled" class="_sizeInput" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="11">11</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-12" 
    class="product-size _product-size " 
    data-sku="01122347" data-name="12">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="12" name="size" id="size-12" 
            class="_sizeInput" tabindex="0">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="12">12</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-13" 
    class="product-size _product-size disabled _disabled " 
    data-sku="01122348" data-name="13">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="13" name="size" id="size-13" 
            disabled="disabled" class="_sizeInput" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="13">13</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-14" 
    class="product-size _product-size " 
    data-sku="01122349" data-name="14">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="14" name="size" id="size-14" 
            class="_sizeInput" tabindex="0">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="14">14</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Now I need to find matches in the text with the string "product-size _product-size " without "disabled _disabled "
and if I find any, check what "size-name" they have.
And I simply stuck (half hour Python user, sorry). Tryed to find simply match with string "product-size _product-size " by using this

```
soup.find_all('label', class_="product-size _product-size ")
soup.find(class_="product-size _product-size ")
soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'product-size _product-size '))
#div.find... or soup.find..., and ect, whatever.
```

But got only [] or None.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use Css selector and :not(class)

```
data='''<div class="size-list" tabindex="-1">
    <label for="size-10" 
    class="product-size _product-size disabled _disabled " 
    data-sku="01122345" data-name="10">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="10" name="size" id="size-10" 
            disabled="disabled" class="_sizeInput" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="10">10</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-11" 
    class="product-size _product-size disabled _disabled " 
    data-sku="01122346" data-name="11">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="11" name="size" id="size-11" 
            disabled="disabled" class="_sizeInput" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="11">11</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-12" 
    class="product-size _product-size " 
    data-sku="01122347" data-name="12">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="12" name="size" id="size-12" 
            class="_sizeInput" tabindex="0">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="12">12</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-13" 
    class="product-size _product-size disabled _disabled " 
    data-sku="01122348" data-name="13">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="13" name="size" id="size-13" 
            disabled="disabled" class="_sizeInput" tabindex="-1">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="13">13</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <label for="size-14" 
    class="product-size _product-size " 
    data-sku="01122349" data-name="14">
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="14" name="size" id="size-14" 
            class="_sizeInput" tabindex="0">
        </div>
        <span class="size-name" title="14">14</span>
        <span></span>
    </label>
</div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('.product-size._product-size:not(.disabled)'):
    print(item.select_one('.size-name').text)
```

Output:

```
12
14
```